# Emberjs : Global menu is not included in every page

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make a global menu with emberjs. Following [these instructions](http://spiegela.com/2014/05/28/writing-a-navigation-bar-controller-in-ember-js/), I have written a `controller/navigation.js` and a `views/navigation.hbs` which render a fixed menu defined in the controller.

I then render the navigation template in `application.hbs` like so:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        {{render 'navigation'}}
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I load up the application at the root url, the menu is rendered as it should. However, as soon as I navigate elsewhere (by clicking an element of the menu, for instance), the menu is not rendered anymore, and if I navigate back to the home page later, the navigation menu is not rendered again.

Why isn't this template rendered every time application.hbs is rendered? What steps should I follow to make sure this menu is rendered with the application?

If it is possible, the navigation menu should have its own controller and template, in order to avoid having all that code in the application controller and template.

Comment: {{partial "navbar"}}
        {{outlet}}
    {{partial "footer"}} // application.hbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is very old. For example, `views` on Ember 2.0 do not exist any more.

If you want a `navbar` in your whole application, you just need to create it in the `application.hbs` template by writing it directly or using a `component`. For example:

```
//application.hbs
<!-- your html code for your navigation menu -->
{{outlet}}
```

or

```
//application.hbs
{{!your component to render your navigation menu}}
{{outlet}}
```

In `{{outlet}}` are loaded all the nested routes of the current route. If you use it in the `application.hbs`, since it is the root path, then the navigation bar will be always visible.

Comment: I'm currently figuring out how to make up data in the routes/application.js model(), but I'll use components to render it. Thanks!